# Combining several JSON objects into one

Tags: ios, json

I need to put an array of JSON objects into a new JSON object.

```
{“megaObject”:[
        {   “key”:8,
            “key2”:”val”
        },
        {   “key”:5,
            “key2”:”val”
        },
        {   “key”:6,
            “key2”:”val”
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created the array like this:

`NSArray *myArray = @[NSData json1, NSData json2, NSData json3];`

Is this the correct way to make a JSON array and if so, how can I put it as a value to key `megaObject.'

I'm new to iOS development so any help is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you represent the JSON object as a `NSDictionary`, you can simply use the methods of this. I.e.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict1;
NSDictionary *jsonDict2;
NSDictionary *jsonDict3;

NSArray *resultAry = @[jsonDict1, jsonDict2, jsonDict3];
NSDictionary *resultDict = @{@"megaObject" : resultAry};
```

and from here on convert to `NSData` or anything else you need ;) First understand what classes you are working with and then look at their methods in the API. Investigate more and concentrate your questions on things that you couldn't solve after at least 2 hours investigation ;)

**UPDATE**

taking a look at your structure...

```
{"megaObject": // <-- NSDictionary "resultDict" with the key "megaObject" and NSArray "resultAry" with 3 NSDictionaries as value.
[
    {   // NSDictionary "jsonDict1" with 2 entries.
        “key”:8,
        “key2”:”val”
    },
    {   “key”:5, // and so on
        “key2”:”val”
    },
    {   “key”:6,
        “key2”:”val”
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Are you sure the data types are correct for the last line? I'm getting a warning saying `incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableDictionary from NSDictionary`.

Comment: If I see your stucture, I am ;) I will explain a bit in an edit

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. How can I print `resultDict` to make sure the format is as I want it?

Comment: if it helped, please accept the answer, and if you want to print an object in console, you may ask google for it ;) i'm sure it will tell you `NSLog(@"%@", obj);` :P

Answer (score 0):

I would use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html), from the documentation:

> You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to reach as result, but this example can help you undersand how to assign an array as value into a NSDictionary as key.

```
  NSDictionary *NEWjSON= [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
  NSArray *myArray = @[
                     @{
                         @"key" : @"8",
                         @"key2" : @"val",
                         },
                     @{   @"key" : @"5",
                          @"key2":@"val",
                          },
                     @{   @"key":@"6",
                          @"key2":@"val"
                          }
                     ];
     [NEWjSON setValue:myArray forKey:@"megaObject"];
```

Comment: I already have the 3 small jsons made separately. Therefore I cant use this method. I'm basically asking how to make a json array from my already existing json strings (NSData) and then make a megaObject using that array.